# Class Association in C# (many to many relation)

Tags: c#, class, associations

I am trying to figure out Class Association (many to many relation).

In the given example, the relation defines as customer can go to many branches and branches can have many customers.

I defined `List<Customer>` as property in `Branch` class and `List<Branch>` in `customer` class as association.

Till this part its fine, but I am unable to display that which customer goes to which branch or which branch have a particular customer.

I tried linq quires and a foreach loop to get the desired result, but I couldn't get them. Please help me out.

```
class Branch
{
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string BranchAddress { get; set; }

    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public void SetCustomerAssociation(List<Customer> customers)
    {
        Customers = customers;
    }
}

class Customer
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

    public List<Branch> Branches { get; set; }

    public void SetBranchAssociation(List<Branch> branches)
    {
        Branches = branches;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Branch> Branches = new List<Branch>(100);
        List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>(100);

        var branch = new Branch();
        Branches.Add(branch);

        var customer = new Customer();
        Customers.Add(customer);

        branch.SetCustomerAssociation(Customers);
        customer.SetBranchAssociation(Branches);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think anyone understands your question. Could you add your attempt or even psuedo-code to demonstrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: My question was that i created a list property in both classes to show many to many association between them but i am unable to find out that which Branch has particular Customer or witch Customer has particular Branch? like a particular customer visits how many branches of a particular store e.g Nike store branches.... All in all I should be able to see which customer belong to which branch?

Answer (score 0):

If you have such a relationship you don't need any loop to get witch **Branch** has particular **Customer** or witch **Customer** has particular **Branch**.

All this information you can get through **Customer.Branches** or **Branch.Customers**.

Of course you can write another method like Customer.HasBranch(Branch branch) and it may look like this:

```
class Customer
{
   ..
  public Branch HasBranch(Branch branch) => Branches.FirstOrDefault(b => b == branch);
}
```

But you must remember if you want to delete some branch you must always delete it from all customers that have it in their lists and vice versa. I think it would be better solution if you create some new class that contains both **Branch** and **Customer** and bind them through this class.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have one more question. I want to take input from user and add multiple customers in a list. how can i create multiple objects of customer and then add it to the list. remember user gives the input.  I have tried but list will only show the last customer added .. ??

Comment: I don't get your point. In what list do you want to add your customers? How looks your user input? If your add something to your list like this ```users.Add(new User())``` multiple times your list will containt all added users.